# Updating json element to json object

Tags: json, local-storage

I am trying to update an element of a JSON object to be an object inside that JSON object.

```
var storedObj = $storage("storedObj").get();
```

This returns something like this

```
storedObj = {
    businessID: 1234,
    businessName: Some Business,
    businessAddress: null
}
```

I want to update businessAddress and re-save the object locally.

```
var bizAddress = {
    city: "City Name",
    state: "State Name",
    Zip: "12345"
}
```

I tried this and it didn't work

```
storedObj.businessAddress = bizAddress;

$storage("storedObj").set(storedObj);
```

Ideally that would restore the entire object with the updated node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's may be becoz of

```
businessName: Some Business,   //   Supposed to be

businessName: 'Some Business',     // Encased in Quotes
```

[WORKING HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SgDkD/)

Comment: Yep you're right, looks like I messed up something in a preivous call.